# Remove characters from the end of the data frame column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with below values and I want to remove last characters i.e - from all the row. How can I do it?

df:

```
Sn  URL
1   Sunil-
2   R-amesh-
3   Oxa--
4   --AB
```

I have below function, how to apply this? Is is it possible to use lambda? Please help?

```
def rchop(thestring, ending):
    if thestring.str.endswith(ending):
       return thestring[:-len(ending)]
    return thestring

df['URL'] = rchop(df['URL'], '-') -- not working
```

Output expected:

```
Sn  URL
1   Sunil
2   R-amesh
3   Oxa
4   --AB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we can use [Series.str.rstrip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

```
In [16]: df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.rstrip('-')

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   Sn      URL
0   1    Sunil
1   2  R-amesh
2   3      Oxa
3   4     --AB
```